# Tail recursion in mutually recursive functions

Tags: recursion, f#, f#-interactive

I have the following code:

```
let rec f n =
    if n < 10 then "f" + g (n+1) else "f"
and g n =
    if n < 10 then "g" + f (n+1) else "g"
```

I want to make these mutually recursive functions tail recursive for optimization. 
I have tried the following :

```
let rec fT n = 
    let rec loop a = 
        if n < 10 then "f" + gT (a) else "f"
    loop (n + 1) 
and gT n =
    let rec loop a = 
        if n < 10 then "g" + fT (a) else "g"
    loop (n + 1)
```

Is that a correct tail recursive version? If no, a hint in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT (Second take on a solution):**

```
let rec fA n = 
    let rec loop n a = 
        if n < 10 then loop (n + 1) ("f" + a) else a
    loop n "f"
and gA n =
    let rec loop n a = 
        if n < 10 then loop (n + 1) ("g" + a) else a
    loop n "g"
```

**EDIT (Third take on a solution):**

```
let rec fA n a = 
    if n < 10 then gA (n + 1) (a + "f") else a
and gA n a =
    if n < 10 then fA (n + 1) (a + "g") else a
```

**EDIT (The correct solution):**

```
let rec fA n a = 
    if n < 10 then gA (n + 1) (a + "f") else (a + "f")
and gA n a =
    if n < 10 then fA (n + 1) (a + "g") else (a + "g")
```

Comment: This is what a "please help me with my homework" question should look like: asking for a hint rather than a solution, so that you can figure it out on your own. **Well done.** The only piece of advice I'd add is: next time, mention up front that it's a homework assignment so you don't want people to just give you the answer. Some people on Stack Overflow can be *too* helpful, so if you say up front "This is homework and I need to figure it out on my own, I just need a small hint" then people can calibrate their answers to the right level of help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution is most definitely *not* tail-recursive.

"Tail-recursion" is such recursion where every recursive call is the *last* thing that the function does. This concept is important, because it means that the runtime can opt out of keeping a stack frame between the calls: since the recursive call is the very last thing, and the calling function doesn't need to do anything else after that, the runtime can skip returning control to the calling function, and have the called function return right to the top-level caller. This allows for expressing recursive algorithms of arbitrary depth without fear of running out of stack space.

In your implementation, however, the function `fT.loop` calls function `gT`, and then prepends "f" to whatever `gT` returned. This prepending of "f" happens *after* `gT` has returned, and therefore the call to `gT` is *not* the last thing that `fT.loop` does. Ergo, it is not tail-recursive.

In order to convert "regular" recursion into the "tail" kind, you have to "turn the logic inside out", so to speak. Let's look at the function `f`: it calls `g` and then prepends "f" to whatever `g` returned. This "f" prefix is the whole "contribution" of function `f` in the total computation. Now, if we want tail recursion, it means we can't make the "contribution" after the recursive call. This means that the contribution has to happen *before*. But if we do the contribution before the call and don't do anything after, then how do we avoid losing that contribution? The only way is to *pass the contribution into the recursive call as argument*.

This is the general idea behind tail-recursive computation: instead of waiting for the nested call to complete and then adding something to the output, we do the adding first and pass what has been "added so far" into the recursive call.

Going back to your specific example: since the contribution of `f` is the "f" character, it needs to add this character to what has been computed "so far" and pass that into the recursive call, which will then do the same, and so on. The "so far" argument should have the semantics of "compute whatever you were going to compute, and then prepend my 'so far' to that".

Since you've only asked for a "hint", and this is obviously homework (forgive me if I'm wrong), I am not going to post the actual code. Let me know if you'd rather I did.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have updated my question above with my new solution, though it does not seem to output the correct values. I wanted to call the inner recursive loop from G in the recursive loop in F, like I call fA in gA and vice versa in my last "solution", though that gives me an error. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You're almost there! Except you haven't quite _fully_ turned the computation "inside out". The original computation _prepended_ the characters to the result of nested calls. Therefore, the transformed computation needs to _append_ them to the result of outside calls. The computation accumulation happens in the opposite order. Also, lose the inner functions: they don't add anything.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I have added my third take on a solution above.

Comment: I see your third solution, and it's still not _quite_ there. Consider the edge case: what happens when you call `f 10`? Does the same thing happen when you call `fA 10 ""`? Why?

Comment: Oh, I see. I just need to add (a + "f") in the else statement in fA and (a + "g")' in gA as well right? Otherwise, fA 10 will return an empty string, since the accumulator is empty from the start. ?

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I second the observation that your attempt definitely does not put the recursion in tail position

How I would handle moving the recursion into tail position would be using a continuation. To do so, we'd have to implement `fk` and `gk` variants which have a continuation parameter, then `f` and `g` can be implemented using `fk` and `gk` respectively

I'm not an F# expert, but I can illustrate this quite simply with JavaScript. I wouldn't ordinarily post an answer using a different language, but since the syntax is so similar, I think it will be helpful to you. It also has the added benefit that you can run this answer in the browser to see it working

```js
// f helper
let fk = (n, k) => {
  if (n < 10)
    return gk(n + 1, g => k("f" + g))
  else
    return k("f")
}
    
// g helper
let gk = (n, k) => {
  if (n < 10)
    return fk(n + 1, f => k("g" + f))
  else
    return k("g")
}
    
let f = n =>
  fk(n, x => x)

let g = n =>
  gk(n, x => x)
  
console.log(f(0))  // fgfgfgfgfgf
console.log(g(0))  // gfgfgfgfgfg
console.log(f(5))  // fgfgfg
console.log(g(5))  // gfgfgf
console.log(f(11)) // f
console.log(g(11)) // g
```

Comment: Continuation passing style is not quite the same as "tail recursion". It's the next step up, and definitely overkill in this situation.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin agreed they are not the same – continuation passing style is one (of several) techniques that can be used to transform a non-tail recursive procedure into a tail recursive one. `fk` and `gk` are tail recursive in this scenario, but I don't see how they're overkill. Admittedly, I don't know F# idioms to handle this, so maybe you could share some code examples with your answer ^_^

Comment: It's an overkill, because, instead of producing the output directly, it creates a tree of closures, which are then executed "in reverse" to produce the output. An extra step, extra time, extra memory.